# are ivars atomic or nonatomic?

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables

I have this private property declared in my `.m` file:

```
@interface HomePages ()
@property (assign, nonatomic) int state;
@end
```

For efficiency reasons in a real time rendering app, I want to eliminate getter/setter calls and change this property to an ivar declared like this:

```
@implementation HomePages {
    int state;
}
```

However, I can't figure out - is this ivar `atomic` or `nonatomic`?

From my reading, I know that the default state for properties is `atomic`, but it also seems that those parenthetical parameters only determine the behavior for getters and setters. Does the concept of `atomic` / `nonatomic` not exist for ivars? are they all `nonatomic`?

Answer (score 3):

The @property syntax is a convenience syntax for creating getters and setters. In this case, you can tell them to create method to access the ivar atomically or non-atomically. Behind the scenes a method is created for you that handles the accessing (which you can override if you wanted, ex: - (int)getState { ... your code ... } to override the getter).

But the ivar is just a variable, so it is nonatomic. There is no code to limit the access to be either atomic or non-atomic. This would be the same case if you used the @property to create the property and ivar with atomic access, and somewhere in your code you used the _state ivar. You are bypassing the accessor and it would always be nonatomic.